# Using spectral cluster algorithm as spatial clustering tool

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gis, cluster-analysis, geospatial

I'm fresh on **Spectral Clustering**. Learning from scikit learn package of Python, I want to take a try.
`X,Y,Z` are three aspect of data represent three independent attributes of each sample(n_samples = 514).
I upload the data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7FE0kxAL8kQcGFpVFZnR2xKcWM)

```
df = pd.read_csv("./test_data,csv")
X  = df.X.as_matrix()
Y  = df.Y.as_matrix()
Z  = df.Z.as_matrix()
data = np.dstack((X, Y, Z))[0,:,:]
spectral = cluster.SpectralClustering(n_clusters=8,
                                      eigen_solver='arpack',)
spectral.fit(data)  
lable_name = spectral.labels_.astype(np.int)
```

The code can run without interrupt, but when I call `label_name`, it shows like

> NameError: name 'label_name' is not defined

#### Supporting information

My target is to cluster the spatial area based on the location(X,Y) and pollutant concentration(Z).

I have already tried to achieve that in `k-means` method, the code and figure shows below:

```
x      =   X / np.linalg.norm(X)
y      =   Y / np.linalg.norm(Y)
z      =   Z / np.linalg.norm(Z)
Samples = np.dstack((X,Y,Z))[0,:,:]
N_REGIONS = 8
labels = KMeans(n_clusters=8, random_state=random_state).fit_predict(Samples)
```

[image]

Then, I want to use `spectral analysis` to see the difference. But several doubts here:

- Why the speed of spectral algorithm is much slower than using k-means?
- Does the `Spectral Clustering` fit my target(**spatial clustering by three attributes which are the geographical location and the concentration there**)
- If reasonable, what parameters setting is recommended?

It would be appreciate if you guys deliver some idea or advice!

Comment: If your data really shows like `array([attr1, attr2. attr3], .......... [attr1, attr2. attr3] )`, then there is something really wrong. Firstly, I expect an extra `[]` around it; secondly, there are `.` where I expect `,`. While I assume most is just bad typing, please double check that your array is indeed of shape `(500, 3)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have re-check my data. But there are some other question appearing. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Your code has `lable_name = spectral.labels_.astype(np.int)`. Change `lable` to `label` and you should be could to go.

Comment: The last two questions are rather open-ended, and might not be a good fit for StackOverflow, but another forum. The question about speed could be a decent question, but 1/ have you tried finding out yourself where that speed difference comes from, and 2/ is it really a problem for your analysis (or are you performing premature optimization)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I didn't find out my low level mistake.

Comment: Spectral clustering is a process to embed your data into a (hopefully) meaningful lower-dimensional space over which you will then use k-means (or some other clustering algo) on. This step requires some level of Eigen decomposition which in its naive implementation is n^3. There are numerous optimizations you can make if you know something about your inputs.